# How to POST from Android to ASP.NET Core 2.1 correctly?

Tags: android, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have UserController in my web app:

```
// POST: api/Users
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostUser([FromBody] User user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

               return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Users.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.Id }, user);
    }
```

And this is my android service:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/Users")
Call<ResponseBody> postUser(@Field("Email") String email, @Field("Pseudonym") String pseudonym, @Field("Points") int points, @Field("Verified") boolean verified, @Field("Banned") boolean banned);
```

In netcore 2.0 it works, but now I created new project in netcore 2.1.

Additionally I got this log:

```
 D/OkHttp: {"":["The input was not valid."]}
```

And 400 bad request

Comment: No answer for you right now, but shoudn't this `return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.Id }, user);` have "PostUser" instead of "GetUser"? Also would you mind showing us the User model? Just in case.

Comment: I dont think so. Look, the return in this case printing what you inserted into table. This is the right way. But I wonder I wrote all I need to publish project on Azure, because in Postman at local host working well when I testing post method. When I change local-host address to server url it returns 500 error.